# Como puedo ocultar un programa de la barra de tareas?

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy intentando hacer un pequeño programa que cuenta palabras, nada del otro mundo. cuando se acaban de contar las palabras sale el icono de python en la barra de tareas, quisiera ocultar ese icono pero que la aplicación siga mostrándose en pantalla. e buscado varias horas en español e ingles y no he encontrado nada! seria de mucha ayuda, gracias.
este es mi código:

```
import sys, os
from pymsgbox import *
import win32gui
import win32console
ventana = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(ventana,0)
n=sys.argv[1]
v=open(n,'r')
p=v.read()
k=0
for u in p:
    k+=1
fin='el texto '+os.path.basename(n)+' tiene '+str(k)+' caracter(es)'
alert(fin, 'contador de palabras')
```

Comment: Con la librería de ```subprocess ``` puedes hacerlo

Comment: @christian me podrías decir como hacerlo?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Bueno con la librería `subprocess` seri un poco más complicado así que te doy una solución más fácil

Primero instalas `pywin32`

```
import win32gui
ventana = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(ventana,0)
```

Eso lo pones antes que todo en tu programa, te dejo la [documentación](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/)

Comment: no funcionó... pude ver que lo que hace es ocultar la consola del python, pero esta ya esta oculta, necesito es ocultar el icono de la barra de tareas

Comment: Por lo que se y he probado esta oculta todo, osea lo pone como si fuera en segundo plano. Podrías agregar una captura de pantalla de lo que tienes y también editar el código con lo que te he dicho

Comment: ya realice las ediciones

Comment: bueno eso sale por que el programa ya termino y te esta mostrando la alerta, si ocultas eso tambien se ira la alerta, no conozco una forma en la que solo te aparezca el mensaje, pero voy a investigar

Comment: y para un programa que necesita la consola abierta? osea si lo único que quiero eliminar es el icono que aparece en la barra de tareas?

Comment: creo que no se puede ya que es la forma en la que windows muestra que se esta ejecutando un programa

Comment: mmm bueno, gracias igualmente por aclararme esa duda.